Created textures break in SDL2 when resizing a window
I'm trying to create and render a large number of textures in a window with a SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE flag, but when I'm resizing it, some textures sometimes break. I haven't noticed this issue if I'm creating a texture in some other way, for example, by rendering a glyph and converting it to a texture. Here's full code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>

SDL_Texture* generateColoredTexture(SDL_Renderer *renderer_, int w_, int h_, const SDL_Color &col_)
{
    auto *tex = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer_, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, w_, h_);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(tex, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    auto oldTar = SDL_GetRenderTarget(renderer_);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer_, tex);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer_, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer_);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer_, col_.r, col_.g, col_.b, col_.a);
    SDL_Rect dst = {4, 4, w_ - 8, h_ - 8};
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer_, &dst);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer_, oldTar);
    return tex;
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{    
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL initialization error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    auto window = SDL_CreateWindow("TestWin", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Window creation error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }

    auto renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
    if (renderer == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Renderer creation error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return -4;
    }

    std::vector<SDL_Texture*> texs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 53; ++i)
    {
        texs.push_back(generateColoredTexture(renderer, 50, 50, {uint8_t(rand() % 255), uint8_t(rand() % 255), uint8_t(rand() % 255), 255}));
    }
    
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> cells;
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; ++y)
    {
        cells.push_back({});
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; ++x)
        {
            cells.back().push_back(rand() % texs.size());
        }
    }

    bool running = true;
    SDL_Event e;

    while (running)
    {
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
        {
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        for (int y = 0; y < cells.size(); ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < cells[y].size(); ++x)
            {
                SDL_Rect dstrect{x * 50, y * 50, 50, 50};
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texs[cells[y][x]], NULL, &dstrect);
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    for (auto *tex : texs)
    {
        SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}

Video of this issue. I haven't found any notes about created textures or window resizing on sdl wiki. I also tried to catch SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED event, but there was none. What causes this issue and is there any solution?
EDIT. I tried to build this code on linux (EndeavourOS, 6.9.3-arch1-1, plasma 6.0.5) and haven't noticed any issues there so I guess its windows-specific

This is usually referred to as "device loss". Look for SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET and SDL_RENDER_DEVICE_RESET events. It indicates that all your render target textures are no longer valid and need to be rerendered. There are some ways to work around that, e.g. using OpenGL renderer or copying your data to non-render textures if contents doesn't change.

@keltar do you mean textures without SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET by "non-render textures"? How can you remove this property or copy to texture without it? I havent found any way to copy texture other than to set it as a render target and render it directly.
Also, is it not an issue on OpenGL?

I think this problem has something to do with SDL's render target setup. Problem occurs when there are more than 2 textures when rendering a single rectangle - after resizing window it will disappear. Switching to maximized state will make it disappear as well, while restoring will make it show again.  No SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET or SDL_RENDER_DEVICE_RESET events happen.

In given example your textures are filled with static colour - you can generate array of pixel data and use that as source of static texture. If your textures are complex (but data is still static) - you can generate it as you do now, and then read texture data to system memory and create static texture from it. If texture is dynamic - it is better to just regenerate it either periodically, or when device loss event is recieved. This is not an issue in OpenGL as OpenGL driver handles it for you and pretends device is never lost.

@keltar Its probably easier to just switch to opengl, but i dont really need to edit texture after rendering it once. My textures in real scenarion are complex but static, do you propose to make an SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING texture without target and copy pixels there instead of keeping SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET?

@SavedowW I don't see any benefit of streaming texture here, static would do just fine. I've gathered everything to an answer, with some examples. If something is unclear feel free to ask for more info in comments

This problem is commonly refered to as "device loss". It was quite common when switching to fullscreen mode (in past times where fullscreen didn't mean "fullscreen window without borders" but actual exclusive fullscreen with video mode change) with Direct3D. D3D provides different flags for texture usage, some of which are automatically restored on device loss, and some are not.
SDL does something similar,automatically recreating all non-rendertarget textures on device loss. See https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/5d1ca1c8c744c51c1d4046b8a10d37f2aea79d0b/src/render/direct3d/SDL_render_d3d.c#L1481 . But for render targets it can't do that effectively (as content of render target could change very frequently, it is impractical to read contents of render target back to system memory just to be able to restore it if device is ever lost), so it gives you special event SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET. Upon that event, your application could rebuild content of render target, or recreate new render target of different size if that is requried to function correctly.
This is not a problem in OpenGL as GL driver itself handles device loss and for your application it seems device is never actually lost (but with GL ES on mobile devices it could be lost; it is only about desktop systems).
So, as I see it, you have 3 options:

use SDL's OpenGL rendering backend, e.g. issue

SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl");

before creating renderer. This is probably not a great solution but it should work.

refresh contents of your render textures when you get SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET event. If your texture creation code contains some randomness, you'll have to save random seed to be able to recreate exactly the same content.

if contents of texture doesn't change, after preparing contents of your render texture, convert it to static texture. E.g. something like:


// ... render to RT texture
Uint32 format;
SDL_QueryTexture(render_texture, &format, NULL, NULL, NULL);

SDL_Texture *static_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, format, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, w, h);
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(static_texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
// in case render_texture and static_texture formats are actually different
SDL_QueryTexture(static_texture, &format, NULL, NULL, NULL);

const int pitch = w * 4;  // presume 4 as we requested RGBA8888
void *pixels = malloc(h * pitch);
// read from current RT (render_texture)
SDL_RenderReadPixels(renderer, NULL, format, pixels, pitch);
SDL_UpdateTexture(static_texture, NULL, pixels, pitch);
free(pixels);


"device loss" typically does not occur when resizing a window. And it certainly does not occur when OP's problem happens. No SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET or SDL_RENDER_DEVICE_RESET events. Moreover, texture content is kept intact and can be rendered if window returns to original size.

@user7860670 it seems you know about OPs problem more than OP themselves, so maybe you should describe it better. Or you have different problem. I get RENDER_TARGETS_RESET event in given example with each resize, and contents of render textures are invalidated after it

@user7860670 https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/5d1ca1c8c744c51c1d4046b8a10d37f2aea79d0b/src/render/direct3d/SDL_render_d3d.c#L293 it does D3D_Reset if size changed. That of course if your render driver is direct3d, which is default for SDL2

Alright, however renderer getting recreated when resizing a window seems to be a separate issue.

@user7860670 i actually do have SDL_RENDER_TARGETS_RESET event, i checked it

@keltar thanks a lot for explanation, i didnt know you could edit texture this way
